# Accessing private variable of one class in another class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, private

How can I access the private variable 'number' of `class B` in another `class A`, in the below code?

```py
    class A:
            def write(self):
                print("hi")

            'It should print the private variable number in class B'
            def check(self):
                print(B.get_number(self))'error occurs here'

        class B:
            def __init__(self,num):
                self.__number = num 

            'accessor method'
            def get_number(self):
                return self.__number

        #driver code        
        obj = B(100)
        a = A()
        a.write()
        a.check()
```

The error message I get is `'A' object has no attribute '_B__number'`

Comment: You *shouldn't* access it. If you wrote `B`, don't use name-mangling to hide the attribute. If someone *else* wrote `B`, then maybe there's a *reason* they are hiding access.

Comment: The current error is because you are passing an instance of `A` to a function that expects an instance of `B`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by changing `check` method to receive `B` object.

Try:

```
class A:
    def write(self):
        print("hi")

    def check(self,b):
        print(b.get_number())

class B:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.__number = num

    'accessor method'

    def get_number(self):
        return self.__number

obj = B(100)
a = A()
a.write()
a.check(obj)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you are trying to read the `__number` field of the object `a` (which is of class `A`) instead of `obj` (which is of class `B`).

The instruction `a.check()` is basically translated to `A.check(self=a)`.  This means that inside the `check()`-method you are then calling `B.get_number(self=a)`, and the `get_number()`-method therefore tries to return `a.__number` (which does not exist).

What you might want to do is this:

```py
    class A:
        def check(self, other):
            print(B.get_number(other)) # <- NOT "self"!

    class B:
        ...

    obj = B(100)
    a = A()
    a.write()
    a.check(obj)
```